# What is the logic behind the interactions of positive and negative energy?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dungeons-and-dragons, osr

Positive and negative energy have a rather idiosyncratic relationship. While ostensibly opposites, creatures and spells that make use of these energies interact in ways that do not seem to follow a consistent pattern in most editions.

- Living creatures are powered by positive energy, except for when they're powered by negative energy (e.g. negative energy elementals, Pathfinder half-undead).
- Magically animated artificial constructs are ostensibly powered by positive energy and yet cannot be affected by spells and effects that manipulate positive or negative energy.
- Undead are powered by negative energy, except for when they're powered by positive energy (e.g. AD&D2e mummies, deathless from Book of Exalted Deeds and Eberron).
- Many undead drain the life force of living creatures to survive (e.g. vampires, wights, spectres, wraiths), even though negative and positive energy are ostensibly opposing forces that mutually annihilate one another.
- Living creatures are healed by positive energy and harmed by negative energy, whereas undead are healed by negative energy and harmed by positive energy. However, there are numerous exceptions to this trend such as radiant damage, necrotic damage, living creatures powered by negative energy, or similar mechanics under different names (e.g. "entropic touch", "channel radiation").
- In certain editions (e.g. pathfinder?), clerics and (anti)paladins manipulate positive or negative energy based on their alignment, which leads to the strange situation where evil factions are easily able to harm living enemies and heal undead allies but are ill-equipped to destroy undead enemies or to heal living allies.

Is there a clear explanation for what these energies are? Was there originally a consistent underlying logic? Was an explanation invented later? Were the rules changed to follow it?

Comment: I've pulled the [tag:ogl] tag, as the question doesn't seem to have anything to do with *using* the OGL, though it does ask about games produced *under* the OGL. Please review the OLG tag description (linked above) and forgive me if I'm wrong. (You can easily edit it back in.)

Comment: Given that the definitions and behaviours of positive energy, negative energy, undead, constructs, life force, radiant damage, and necrotic damage all change from one edition to the next, I'm voting to close this question as Too Broad until it's scoped to a particular edition.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it looks like you're trying to find a cross-edition answer, but that is going to be really hard to pull off becuase game design philosopies changed over the years and some of your examples clearly show so (and this should answer your last question properly).

- In D&D 4e, radiant and necrotic are just two different types of damage, just like fire and lightning and thunder (sonic).
  The game just treats this as holy/unholy damage and some creatures resist to it or are more vulnerable to it, like you would explect in many computer games, because there are codified ways damage applies. Resistance, immunity and vulnerability are ok in the game, "this heals instead of dealing damage" is worth to be a special defense of a specific monster.
  Also, in D&D 4e, healing spells do not harm undead. It is a very different game than the other editions.
  (Still, some undead do feed on life force, as shown by soul-rending attacks that remove healing surges.)

Then, we get an early classification that still screams holy/unholy.

- Some undead have been raised because of dissacration (necromancy used to steal people's bodies or souls and bind them to the necromancer's bidding, using negative energy to keep the corpses together), and some are just preserved corpses created by a funerary ritual that is intended to help the soul of the deceased. Mummies are powered by holy energy.
- 3e tried to uniform that, and every undead was then powered by unholy (negative) energy. Undeads do not feed on positive energy, they do feed on life force. Humans are not powered by positive energy the same way undead are kept together by negative energy, but positive energy heals them. Or, if too much is applied, makes them explode.
- Negative energy is still an alternative way to life force for powering bodies. So we have half undeads, or some construct that can be powered by negative energy.
  The negative energy elemental looks like a creature made of the stuff a plane is made, just like the fire elemental is made from the stuff of the plane of fire or the water elemental is... well, I guess you get the gist.
  The fact that raw negative energy harms living creatures (just like fire does) stands. It needs to be tamed and manipulated in special ways to be able to power a body.
- Most animated creatures are animated by arcane energy, anyway.
- Then, some authors decided that they wanted to create some exceptions, introducing good liches (the Baelorn) and undeads powered by positive energy. This looks like the same process that brought to good poisons (ravages) and to a good drow goddess, or to evil fallen angels.